# SSH user not getting authenticated through kerberos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sshd, kerberos

I have setup kerberos in my ubuntu machine and I am able to get tickets for users via `kinit` from my other Fedora Linux client machine.

But getting below error in sshd debug logs, no idea what it means:

```
debug1: userauth-request for user user1 service ssh-connection method gssapi-with-mic [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
Postponed gssapi-with-mic for user1 from 10.87.198.85 port 55360 ssh2 [preauth]
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Request ticket server host/kdc.sat.com@SAT.COM found in keytab but does not match server principal host/sat.com@

debug1: Got no client credentials
debug1: userauth-request for user user1 service ssh-connection method gssapi-with-mic [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
```

My sshd and KDC are running in the same machine, with below config:

major components of krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = SAT.COM

[realms]
        SAT.COM = {
                kdc = kdc.sat.com
                admin_server = kdc.sat.com
        }
```

My /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.125.222.30   kdc.sat.com


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Principals in my KDC are as below:

```
kadmin:  listprincs 
K/M@SAT.COM
host/kdc.sat.com@SAT.COM
host/sat.com@SAT.COM
kadmin/admin@SAT.COM
kadmin/changepw@SAT.COM
kadmin/localhost@SAT.COM
kiprop/localhost@SAT.COM
krbtgt/SAT.COM@SAT.COM
satyam/admin@SAT.COM
user1@SAT.COM
```

When I do initial kinit from my fedora client I get just one ticket as below:

```
[user1@satyam ~]$ kinit 
Password for user1@SAT.COM: 
[user1@satyam ~]$ klist 
Ticket cache: KCM:1001
Default principal: user1@SAT.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/24/2019 19:32:46  09/25/2019 05:32:46  krbtgt/SAT.COM@SAT.COM
    renew until 10/01/2019 19:32:41
```

But as soon as I do ssh to my sshd server which is same as KDC server my klist has more entries:

```
[user1@satyam ~]$ ssh kdc.sat.com
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Satyam
user1@kdc.sat.com's password: 

    [satyam@satyam ~]$ klist 
Ticket cache: KCM:1000
Default principal: user1@SAT.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/24/2019 19:44:59  09/25/2019 05:41:14  host/kdc.sat.com@
    renew until 10/01/2019 19:41:10
09/24/2019 19:41:14  09/25/2019 05:41:14  krbtgt/SAT.COM@SAT.COM
    renew until 10/01/2019 19:41:10
09/24/2019 19:44:59  09/25/2019 05:41:14  host/kdc.sat.com@SAT.COM
    renew until 10/01/2019 19:41:10
```

Also Principal host/sat.com@SAT.COM was not added earlier but then I got below error in sshd so I tried adding it but still no luck:

```
No key table entry found matching host/sat.com@
```

Any help regarding this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing lot of online googling and found below configuration parameter which somehow resolved the issue:

Param I used:

```
[libdefaults]
    ignore_acceptor_hostname = true
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687245/apache-sends-wrong-server-principal-name-to-kerberos

In above SO thread although there is an explanation but still I didn't quite understand how it worked and what was the issue.

Please still if anyone can explain how this config param solved my issue that would be great.

Comment: On my SLES if `hostnamectl --static` does not return FQDN, then `sshd` searches only `host/<machine name>@` instead of `host/<fqdn>@<REALM>`. See also details at https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/user/user_config/kerberos.html.